# Access Angular scope of controller in nested partial

Tags: angularjs

In my Angular project each page has a controller. I include a partial that is used on multiple pages. In each controller I initialize some values then access them inside the partial.

```
$scope.checkedItems = [];
```

The in the partial I bind data to it.

```
<input type="checkbox" checklist-model="$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.$parent.checkedItems" checklist-value="item.Id">
```

The partial is nested so I have to use $parent multiple times to access the parameter within the controller's scope. This is very ugly. Also, the partial is included in different places on different pages, so the scope depth isn't consistent. Therefore on some pages I need to go up 5 levels, 8 levels, 4 levels, etc.

Is there an easier way to access the controller's scope? It'd be great if the following worked.

```
<input type="checkbox" checklist-model="$controllerScope.checkedItems" checklist-value="item.Id">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a data source as a factory.

**Factory:**

```
define([], function () {

'use strict';


function checkedItemsDataSource(){

    var dataSource = {};

    dataSource.items = [];

    dataSource.setItems = function(items){
        dataSource.items = items;
    };

    return dataSource;

}

return checkedItemsDataSource;

});
```

In the **controller**, set checked items to an empty array as the initial value. Create a variable with the factory as it's value.

```
checkedItemsDataSource.setItems([]);
$scope.checkedItemsDataSource = checkedItemsDataSource;
```

When data needs to be changed in any other controller or nested scope, call the factory's setItems function. The value of $scope.checkedItemsDataSource will automatically update.

Answer (score 0):

create one service for data exchange between controllers

---

### nested tree option

in service create an object with parent->child structure, in nested template store some unique id to tell service where to store your data in nested tree

in context of template it will look clean but all the logic will be transferred to service

so in template you will have something like:

```
<input type="checkbox" ng-checked="checked">
```

and in controller:

```
$scope.uniqueid='3je99ehr0jer';//generate something...
$scope.checked=false;
yourService.set($scope.uniqueid,$scope.$parent.uniqueid,$scope.checked,function(checked){
  $scope.checked=checked;
});
//where first arg is controller unique id and second parent controller uniqueid
$scope.$watch('checked',(...notify service to change data in tree...));
```

when you want to collect full tree just use something like yourService.getAll()

the tree structure shoul look like:

```
scope.dataTree={
  '3je99ehr0jer':{checked:true,children:[ another nodes that have parentid 3je99... ]}
}
```

to add/change dataTree use some recursive function to find ids that you need

```
yourService.set = function serviceSet(currentId,parentId,data,onChange){
  //find recursively parentId if not null
  // update value
  // notify parent node (or all) controllers that something has changed if you need (onChange argument)
}
```

---

### flat object option

If you want just flat object with item.id->value content then it will be simplier because instead of dataTree in yourService you can use data like:

```
scope.data= {
  '3je99ehr0jer':false,
  '03kefkeo0efe':true,
  ...
}
```

Now you don't need to recursively find ids but only get what you want from scope.data object `scope.data['3je99ehr0jer']`

---

I'am too lazy to test this approach but you will figure out how to correct something, I'm not sure at this point that you need notify `yourService` that something has changed with `$watch` method and if `onChange` method in `yourService` is needed also but you will figure out this, the concept seems to be correct -> **service for data exchange based on unique id**

If you find bugs tell me in comment so I can edit this answer

Comment: Thanks, but I ended up using a service (factory) that is much simpler.